# Is it possible for HTTP server to receive requests out of order even if they are sent sequentially?

Tags: c#, http

(This discussion might not be specific to C#...)

I have a C# method `SendMultipleRequests` that sends HTTP POST request 10 times sequentially.
Is it possible for the server to receive requests out of order?
If my understanding is correct if the requests are sent concurrently (without `await`), the server could receive requests out of order, but in the example below it needs to wait for the response to be received at the client before sending next request, so the server will receive requests in order.

```cs
public async Task SendRequest(int i) 
{
  // definition of endpoint is omitted in this example
  var content = new StringContent($"I am {i}-th request");
  await HttpClient.PostAsync(endpoint, content);
}

public async Task SendMultipleRequests() 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    await SendRequest(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking “if I remove the await, might the server see the requests on a different order?” - you’ve already got the test code; why not test it?

Comment: I am asking "even with await, might the server see the requests on a different order?"

Comment: No, with await your app will wait for PostAsync to return before it issues the next request - see the docs for postasync where it says “This operation will not block. The returned Task<TResult> object will complete after the whole response (including content) is read.” - using await will mean that you will only issue the next request after you I’ve read the content of the previous response

Comment: Does it mean the server will never receive requests out of order?

Comment: Also, what happens if I remove await?

Comment: If you remove the await then your code will queue up ten tasks and start working on them all in some undefined order. The server will see requests in an unspecified order. This may be further exacerbated by the fact that the requests may take different routes through the internet, some slower. If you remove the await then you should capture the returned task into a list, then you can use something like `await Task.WhenAll(list)` to wait for them all to complete

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `await` your app will wait for the task returned by PostAsync to finish before it issues the next request - see the docs for postasync where it says “This operation will not block. The returned `Task<TResult>` object will complete after the whole response (including content) is read.” - using await will mean that you will only issue the next request after you I’ve read the content of the previous response

If you remove the await then your code will queue up ten tasks and start working on them all in some undefined order. The server will see requests in an unspecified order. This may be further exacerbated by the fact that the requests may take different routes through the internet, some slower. If you remove the await then you should capture the returned task into a list, then you can use something like await Task.WhenAll(list) to wait for them all to complete (unless you really want to fire and forget in which case you can assign them to the discard `_ = client.PostAsync...` but keeping the task allows you to discover and deal with exceptions that arose)